# Return object created in a try catch

Tags: c#, oop

What is the best/correct way to do the following and return either an object or null?

If I declare the return Dictionary object in the try/catch clause it may not return an object and will generate a compile error because of that.  But it should at least return something, like null?

```
public static Dictionary<string,string> myFunction()
{
    try {
        ...
        Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary();
    }

    catch {
        ...
    }

    return dict;
}
```

Do I just instantiate the returned object outside of the try/catch and test for the returned value/length back in the calling program?

Comment: The short answer is, it totally depends. Post a real use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> myFunction()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = null;
    try
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    return dict;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Arin.  This seems like the best solution as so often I have code that exists outside of my try..catch that I need to execute after the try..catch, but before I return to the caller.  I guess I could always wrap every bit of code inside my try...catch, but that doesn't always seem practical.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> myFunction()
{
    try
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict;

        dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // do something with dict

        return dict;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle ex
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Return your `Dictionary` end of your `try` block, return `null` from your `catch`.And every time you call this function check for returning value.If it's null then that means something bad happened.

So it is totally **OK** if you want to define your `Dictionary` inside of your `try` block, actually is it better:

```
try 
{
    Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary();
    ...

    return dict;
}

catch 
{
    ...
    return null;
}
```

Because returning a null `Dictionary` is the same as returning `null` directly.And it is always better to restrict variable scope if you don't need that variable outside of your scope.

Answer (score 0):

Correct move the dictionary declaration outside the try block. Otherwise catch cannot reference the dictionary defined in the try block as it would be out of scope.